# Convert XML to CSV in C#

Tags: c#, csv, xml-parsing

This is how my XML looks like.

I need to convert the  xml to csv in C#.Can anyone please help.

Comment: Initially Your xml is wrong. You need closing ABC

Comment: What kind of problems are you getting with your code? If you showed what you tried so far maybe we could see what's the problem with your code.

Comment: Why did you edit out the XML from your question? It makes no sense at all in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass your string to datatable. Then the things are simple

```
        string xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?> 
        <DOCUMENT> 
           <ABCS> 
             <ABC> 
               <abc_id style_sid=""-4939636236138949558"" style_code=""""/> 
               <abc item_sid=""-4939635934019714433"" upc=""30109"" use_qty_decimals=""0"" prod_cost="""" reclass_item_sid=""""/> 
               <abc_c_d> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""1"" value=""""/>
                <abc_c_ds no=""2"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""3"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""4"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""5"" value=""""/>
                <abc_c_ds no=""6"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""7"" value=""""/>
                <abc_c_ds no=""8"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""9"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""10"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""11"" value=""""/>
                <abc_c_ds no=""12"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""13"" value=""""/> 
                <abc_c_ds no=""14"" value=""""/>
              </abc_c_d>
           </ABC>
        </ABCS> 
      </DOCUMENT>";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);

        ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
```

Comment: Hi kostas ch.Thanks for the answer but i am getting the below error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: I run the code and run fine.

Comment: Have copy paste the exact code?? Not your xml because is wrong